# PDF with custom character tables

Tags: pdf, character-encoding

I have a problem with reading international ice hockey federation IIHF's statistics PDF's. When I open them with a normal PDF reader they show up nicely, but when I try to for example copypaste from them or convert them to plain text it just doesn't work.

An example can be found here: http://stats.iihf.com/siha/30/IHM030901_74_3_0.pdf

Does anyone know how can I convert them so that I could handle them as plain text. Preferably so that it could be done with a command line utility so that it could be automatized.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you look at the properties of the file in your PDF reader, you’ll see that it contains CID Identity-H fonts. This means that the encoding of the fonts is specified in the font. There are some existing questions on Identity-H fonts, but none of them seem to have a useful answer, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779551/how-to-get-text-from-identity-h-encoded-from-pdf

Comment: I hope someone will prove me wrong, but I don't think you'll be able to convert the test. The file uses Adobe Identity-H font encoding.

Comment: As the document font encoding is Identity-H (as the other comments already pointed out) and there are not **ToUnicode** mappings, the PDF specification concerning *Extraction of Text Content* (section 9.10) from your PDF says: *If these methods fail to produce a Unicode value, there is no way to determine what the character code represents.*

Comment: So there is no way to manually write this method somehow with any utility? It would be less time consuming than copying all the contents of those PDFs manually anyway.

Comment: I don't think there is any chance - I looked at the fonts in more detail and the fonts in the file are highly incomplete. They contain minimal font tables and even incorrect information in some tables. The actual bytes in the page contain seem to have been written in a custom encoding, not one of the standard system encodings, so even bypassing the font itself would not be a solution. Furthermore I believe some form of subsetting has been used while embedded (even if not done correctly) so the encoding would likely even differ between files...